# Pre-increment assginement as Row Number to List

Tags: list, c#-4.0

i trying to assign a row number and a Set-number for List, but Set Number containing wrong number of rows in one set.

```
 var objx = new List<x>();
            var i = 0;
            var r = 1;


            objY.ForEach(x => objx .Add(new x 
                                                  {
                                                      RowNumber = ++i,
                                                      DatabaseID= x.QuestionID,
                                                      SetID= i == 5 ? r++ : i % 5 == 0 ? r += 1 : r
                                                  }));
```

for Above code like objY Contains 23 rows, and i want to break 23 rows in 5-5 set. 
so above code will give the sequence like[**Consider only RowNumber**]

```
[1 2 3 4 5][6 7 8 9][ 10 11 12 13 14 ].......
```

its a valid as by the logic
and if i change the logic for Setid as

```
 SetID= i % 5 == 0 ? r += 1 : r
```

Result Will come Like

```
[1 2 3 4 ][5 6 7 8 9][10 11 12 13 14].
```

Again correct output of code

but expected for set of 5.

```
[1 2 3 4 5][ 6  7 8 9 10].........
```

What i missing.............

i should have taken my Maths class very Serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var objX = objY.Select((x, i) => new { ObjX = x, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 5)
    .Select((g, i) => 
        g.Select(x => new objx
        {
            RowNumber = x.Index + 1
            DatabaseID = x.ObjX.QuestionID,
            SetID = i + 1
        }).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Note that i'm grouping by `x.Index / 5` to ensure that every group has 5 items.

[**Here's a demo**](http://ideone.com/RZGDVB).

**Update**

> it will be very helpful,if you can explain your logic

Where should i start? I'm using Linq methods to select and group the original list to create a new `List<List<ObjX>>` where every inner list has maximum 5 elements(less in the last if the total-count is not dividable by 5).

[`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) enables to *project* something from the input sequence to create something new. This method is comparable to a variable in a loop. In this case i project an anonymous type with the original object and the index of it in the list(`Select` has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that incorporates the index). I create this anonymous type to simply the query and because i need the index later in the GroupBy``.

[`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) enables to group the elements in a sequence by a specified key. This key can be anything which is derivable from the element. Here i'm using the index two build groups of a maximum size of 5:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Index / 5)
```

That works because integer division in C# (or C) results always in an `int`, where the remainder is truncated(unlike VB.NET btw), so **3/4 results in 0**. You can use this fact to build groups of the specified size.

Then i use `Select` on the groups to create the inner lists, again by using the index-overload to be able to set the `SetId` of the group:

```
.Select((g, i) => 
    g.Select(x => new objx
    {
        RowNumber = x.Index + 1
        DatabaseID = x.ObjX.QuestionID,
        SetID = i + 1
    }).ToList())
```

The last step is using `ToList` on the `IEnumerable<List<ObjX>>` to create the final `List<List<ObX>>`. That also "materializes" the query.  Have a look at [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq) and especially [**Jon Skeets blog**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx) to learn more.

Comment: alas, it still gives me `
  In  [0]: Count = 4
  In  [1]: Count = 5
  In  [2]: Count = 5
  In  [3]: Count = 5

Comment: @joshua: Edited my answer (changed `Index = i+1` to `Index = i`). Added also a demo.

Comment: it will be very helpful,if you can explain your logic

Comment: @joshua: Edited my answer and added some explaining words.