# List sorting by multiple parameters

Tags: c#, sorting, csv

I have a .csv with the following headers and an example line from the file.

```
AgentID,Profile,Avatar,In_Time,Out_Time,In_Location,Out_Location,Target_Speed(m/s),Distance_Traveled(m),Congested_Duration(s),Total_Duration(s),LOS_A_Duration(s),LOS_B_Duration(s),LOS_C_Duration(s),LOS_D_Duration(s),LOS_E_Duration(s),LOS_F_Duration(s)
2177,DefaultProfile,DarkGreen_LowPoly,08:00:00,08:00:53,East12SubwayportalActor,EWConcourseportalActor,1.39653,60.2243,5.4,52.8,26.4,23,3.4,0,0,0
```

I need to sort this .csv by the 4th column (In_time) by increasing time ( 08:00:00, 08:00:01) and the 6th (In_Location) by alphabetical direction (e.g. East, North, etc).

So far my code looks like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("JourneyTimes.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line.Split(',');
        list.Add(line);
    }
```

I read in the .csv and split it using a comma (there are no other commas so this is not a concern). I then add each line to a list. My issue is how do I sort the list on two parameters and by the headers of the .csv.

I have been looking all day at this, I am relatively new to programming, this is my first program so I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You split the line (`line.Split(',');`) and throw away the result.

Comment: Firstly, you're ignoring the return value of `string.Split` - it's as if you weren't calling it. What are you expecting it to do? Secondly, I'd strongly advise you to create a class to represent all the values in a single line of text. Parse each line, and add it to the list as a new object of that appropriate type. (We can't really tell what this data is meant to be, unfortunately, so it's hard to give a sample name.)

Comment: I would use a CSV reader (written by someone else) to turn the data into a `List<string>` (if this is the only usage I likely wouldn't type it further). Then I would use `IEnumerable.OrderBy` (which works nicely with a compound ordering) and use a CSV writer (written by someone else) to spit everything back out again. Or, I'd use Excel :D

Comment: @Eltneg I can't "rep", but I don't think it deserves a +1 either .. most of this question is about things that don't apply and there is no minimal question (with minimal data) of "how can I order this list of [..]?" or perhaps "how can I read in CSV data?" (which is another question) .. and both, as single questions, are highly duplicated. As a compound question it's too-localized and unfocused.

Comment: I would suggest using a `TextFieldParser` or another proper CSV parser rather than just using `string.Split` to handle non-trivial input data, such as quote enclosed fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `LINQ` [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)/[ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx):

e.g.

```
listOfObjects.OrderBy (c => c.LastName).ThenBy (c => c.FirstName)
```

But first off, you should map your `CSV` line to some object.
To map `CSV` line to object you can predefine some type or create it dynamically

```
from line in File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(1) //header
let columns = line.Split(',') //really basic CSV parsing, consider removing empty entries and supporting quotes
select new
{
  AgentID = columns[0],
  Profile = int.Parse(columns[1]),
  Avatar = float.Parse(columns[2])
  //other properties
}
```

And be aware that like many other LINQ methods, these two use [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

Comment: Not without significantly more work. The OP is a *long* way from this being appropriate.

Comment: @JonSkeet extended my answer so that it now looks more helpful for OP

Comment: Right, that's a lot more helpful. You should probably also mention that `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` won't be sorting in place...

Comment: Don't use `ReadAllLines` unless you have a compelling reason to; you should be using `ReadLines` here and streaming the data.

Comment: @Servy thanks for pointing me to that, have no access to VS right now, my bad. ReadLines plays well with select/orderby/thenby in this case

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `DataTable`:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var columNames = lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
for (int i = 0; i < columNames.Length; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(columNames[i]);
}

for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' }));
}

var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var result = rows.OrderBy(i => i["In_time"])
    .ThenBy(i => i["In_Location"]);

// sum
var sum = rows.Sum(i => Int32.Parse(i["AgentID"].ToString()));
```

Comment: This looks beautiful. After the sorting, can I readily apply column operations to this?

For example, can I sum the values for a particular column within the datatable?

Comment: You can sum the values in one column, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two distinct problems.

First, ordering two columns in C# can be achieved with OrderBy, ThenBy

```
public class SpreadsheetExample
{
    public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
    public string InLocation { get; set; }

    public SpreadsheetExample(DateTime inTime, string inLocation)
    {
        InTime = inTime;
        InLocation = inLocation;
    }

    public static List<SpreadsheetExample> LoadMockData()
    {
        int maxMock = 10;
        Random random = new Random();
        var result = new List<SpreadsheetExample>();
        for (int mockCount = 0; mockCount < maxMock; mockCount++)
        {
            var genNumber = random.Next(1, maxMock);
            var genDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(genNumber);
            result.Add(new SpreadsheetExample(genDate, "Location" + mockCount));
        }

        return result;
    }
}

internal class Class1
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var mockData = SpreadsheetExample.LoadMockData();
        var orderedResult = mockData.OrderBy(m => m.InTime).ThenBy(m => m.InLocation);//Order, ThenBy can be used to perform ordering of two columns

        foreach (var item in orderedResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.InTime, item.InLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can tackle the second issue of moving data into a class from Excel.  [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) is what you are looking for.  There are lots of [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128771.aspx) online.  Follow the example I posted above.  Replace your custom class in place of `SpreadSheetExample`.