# Can anyone let me know why it happens in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
nums.Add(1);
nums.Add(4);
nums.Add(2);
var lowNums = from n in nums
              where n%2==0
              select n;

 Console.WriteLine("Even Numbers before adding 20 :");
 foreach (var x in lowNums)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(x);
 }

 nums.Add(20);
 Console.WriteLine("Even Numbers after adding 20:");
 foreach (var x in lowNums)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(x);
 }
```

Here while running this,it gives me this output:

[image].

But I wonder why it shows 20 because I am not running the LINQ expression after I add 20. I just display the previously calculated result. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Running a LINQ query returns an enumerable; `foreach` iterates over it. The enumerable keeps a reference to its input and produces the output as you’re using it; a `foreach` loop creates a new enumerator each time.

Comment: The Linq query doesn't actually get executed when you declare it.  It gets executed when you *request output from it,* which is what you're doing with the `foreach` loops.  Your Linq query is getting executed twice, in other words, once for each `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not *running* the LINQ expression, you are creating it. The expression gets executed when it is needed, which is often referred to as *deferred execution*.

When stepping into that code you can see that `lowNums` is actually of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<int>` which is an expression, not a result.

By looping over the expression the results are recalculated. If you want to explicitly execute the expression and store the results use `.ToList()` on the expression.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It's ok, no slapping required ;)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ queries are evaluated when you  iterate over `lowNums` using `foreach`

LINQ queries provide deferred execution and they don't have their own backing structure to store the elements..

It's like a conveyor belt which rolls elements **only on demand**..

Comment: Thanks to all of you. It's because of deferred execution as I got from the above answers. It really helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq also helps understanding this concept