# Why does LINQ not cache enumerations?

Tags: c#, linq, caching

So it is my understanding that LINQ does not execute everything immediately, it simply stores information to get at the data. So if you do a `Where`, nothing actually happens to the list, you just get an `IEnumerable` that has the information it needs to become the list.

One can 'collapse' this information to an actual list by calling `ToList`.

Now I am wondering, why would the LINQ team implement it like this? It is pretty easy to add a `List` at each step (or a `Dictionary`) to cache the results that have already been calculated, so I guess there must be a good reason.

This can be checked by this code:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(i => {
    Console.WriteLine("Enumerating: " + i);
    return true;
});

var list2 = list.All(i => {
    return true;
});

var list3 = list.Any(i => {
    return false;
});
```

If the cache were there, it would only output the `Enumerating: i` once for each number, it would get the items from the cache the second time.

**Edit:** Additional question, why does LINQ not include a cache option? Like `.Cache()` to cache the result of the previous enumerable?

Comment: What happens if you're building a list against a data source (i.e. database)?  Do you really want it to evaluate the result of every enumeration immediately?  Most often the answer is no.

Comment: @Yuck no not immediately, but it has "calculated" the values once, why not cache them and use them instead of calculating them instead?

Comment: Well, isn't it nice that they let you decide what you want? It is as simple  as doing <code>Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();</code> if you need to iterate over the list more than once.

Comment: Indeed - it's much easier to explicitly cache than it is to work around caching occurring when you *don't* want it to.

Comment: @PeterBons yes, that is a good point, but then I enumerate the entire list, what if I am constantly accessing the same 5 elements in a list of 30000?

Comment: Who knows you go over the results multiple times? @vrwim

Comment: @vrwim then do a .Where on the elements you need the most and do a .ToList() on that subset. Again, I like it that I am in control when things happen. The way it is setup now you can decide. If the innerworkings would call .ToList() for me I would not be able to influence the 'when'

Comment: Also have a read of this thread around Deferred Execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq I also find the tools in System.Runtime.Caching a good companion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As an aside, please don't become one of those coders who tacks `.ToList()` on to the end of every single statement involving an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Yuck I don't do it now and I don't want to do it, but I want to reuse items I know will be accessed multiple times. Guess I'll be making my own IEnumerable extension method with caching

Comment: @Yuck :While i was reading this question and i found your comment "please don't become one of those coders who tacks .ToList() on to the end of every single statement involving an IEnumerable" which relates to me because i am always doing this.so can you please tell me what do you mean by this statement and when not to do .tolist() and when to do it.please??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it makes no sense, and if you would think about all the cases where it makes no sense you would not ask it. This is not so much a "does it sometimes make sense" question as a "are there side effects that make it bad". Next time you evaluate something like this, think about the negatives:

- Memory consumption goes up as you HAVE to cache the results, even if not wanted.
- On then ext run, the results may be different as incoming data may have changed. your simplistic example (Enumerable.Range) has no issue with that - but filtering a list of customers may have them updated.

Stuff like that makes is very hard to sensibly take away the choice from the developer. Want a buffer, make one (easily). But the side effects would be bad.

Comment: That makes sense. But why does LINQ not have a `.Cache()` option?

Comment: It has, it is called `ToList()`, `ToArray()` and `ToDictionary()` @vrwim

Comment: Nope, ToList enumerates the entire list, I want an option that caches the items I have accessed. What if I only ever access 5 elements in a 30000 item list? I know I could make it, but why doesn't it exist already in the framework?

Comment: @vrwim What exactly would you expect a `Cache` method to do that `ToList` doesn't?  If you want to cache the 5 items then it has to first iterate the entire list to find them.

Comment: I want it to cache the elements I have accessed, to prevent the entire `IEnumerable` from being calculated multiple times. `ToList` just calculates all items, even if I never access them. In my example these could have been the 5 first items, to point out the obvious performance improvement.

Comment: I would expect it to cache *lazily*, as enumeration happens.

Answer (score 6):

> It is pretty easy to add a List at each step

Yes, and very memory intensive. What if the data set contains 2 GB of data in total, and you have to store that in memory at once. If you iterate over it and fetch it in parts, you don't have a lot of memory pressure. When serializing 2 GB to memory you do, not to imagine what happens if every step will do the same...

You know your code and your specific use case, so only you as a developer can determine when it is useful to split off some iterations to memory. The framework can't know that.

Comment: What if I am constantly accessing the same 5 elements in a list of 30000? The cache would only keep the 5 elements in memory.

Comment: But who knows that? It is very hard to build an efficient caching mechanism, especially when you don't know the use case of it.