# Linq to objects multiple statements vs. single statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In Linq to objects is there any difference in the execution between this code:

```
var changedFileIDs = updatedFiles.Where(file => file.CurrentVersion != file.OriginalVersion).Select(file => file.ID);
var changedVaultFiles = filesToUpdate.Where(x => changedFileIDs.Contains(x.ID));
foreach (var file in changedVaultFiles)
{
    Vault.Upload(file);
}
```

and this code?

```
var changedVaultFiles = filesToUpdate.Where(x => updatedFiles.Where(file => file.CurrentVersion != file.OriginalVersion).Select(file => file.ID).Contains(x.ID));
foreach (var file in changedVaultFiles)
{
    Vault.Upload(file);
}
```

Comment: No, no difference in performance. (unless you didn't call `ToArray` on the first collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no difference in performance, because one of the features of Linq is [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq), in other words, your query is not going to be executed until the query variable is iterated over in a `foreach` or `for`, or calling `ToList` or `ToArray` extension method. So in your first example your are composing your main query but is not going to be executed until you iterate over it.

You will find in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx) more details about how query execution works in LINQ.

Summary of *Deferred Execution*:

> After a LINQ query is created by a user, it is converted to an command
>   tree. A command tree is a representation of a query.The command tree
>   is then executed against the data source when the query variable is
>   iterated over, not when the query variable is created. At query
>   execution time, all query expressions (that is, all components of the
>   query) are evaluated, including those expressions that are used in
>   result materialization.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wanted confirmation and couldn't find any sources that stated it explicitly. Perhaps I was just using the wrong search terms.