# Linq select strange effect

Tags: c#, linq

I have noticed strange Linq `select` behavior in program below:

```
IEnumerable<string> s = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var i = s.Select(url =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        url = string.Format("--{0}--",url);
        return url;
    }
);

Console.WriteLine("done with selector");
foreach (string f in i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("f is {0}", f);
}
```

Output is:

```
1
f is --1--
2
f is --2--
3
f is --3--
```

I was expecting output to be :

```
1
2
3
f is --1--
f is --2--
f is --3--
```

How to explain such strange behavior? Is it some kind of code optimization?

Comment: Why did you expect the second output? LINQ is lazy evaluated.

Comment: This is called "deferred execution". Yes, it's some kind of code optimization. The code to generate the sequence is not executed until someone actually iterates it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a perfect illustration to the way *deferred execution* works in LINQ:

- The line `"done with selector"` is printed first because `Select` "remembers" the info for computing the sequence, without actually computing it
- The lines coming from the lambda inside `Select` and from `WriteLine` inside the loop are interleaved, because the sequence is generated as you continue enumerating it
- If you break out of the loop in the middle of the sequence, the rest of printouts from the lambda will never come.

If you add `ToList` after `Select`, your code will produce the sequence "eagerly", leading to the output that you expect ([demo](https://ideone.com/eHwHDV)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    IEnumerable<string> s = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
    var i = s.Select(url =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url);
            url = string.Format("--{0}--",url);
            return url;
        }
    ).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("done with selector");
    foreach (string f in i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("f is {0}", f);
    }
```

Due to deferred execution, the lambda expression in the first line will only execute when the result is iterated in the second line.

This behavior is completely correct.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/) is a very good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you were expecting was for the query to execute and populate the variable `i` where you define the query.

This behaviour can be forced (and often is unnecessarily in less well written code) by casting .ToList() after the select like so:

```
IEnumerable<string> s = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var i = s.Select(url =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        url = string.Format("--{0}--",url);
        return url;
    }
).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("done with selector");
foreach (string f in i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("f is {0}", f);
}
```

but it is rarely necessary.

This behaviour is similar to that experienced when using the [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) and yield return keywords in c#. It may be worth you looking into them a little.