# Does in Linq where creates a new instance of object

Tags: c#, linq

In below code why `filteredStudentNames` holds only 2 elements.
As per my understanding, it is reference type so when I update the `studentList` object with one more item that results should also be part of `filteredStudentNames`.

In the case of `studentNames` object, I am getting the updated record also.
So why not in the case of `filteredStudentnames`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
                    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", age = 18 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  age = 21 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  age = 18 } ,
                    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , age = 20  } ,
                    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , age = 21 }
                };

        var filteredStudentNames = from s in studentList 
                                   where s.age > 20
                                   select s;

        var studentNames = from s in studentList
                           select s;

        IList<Student> stud = studentList;
        studentList.Add(new Student { StudentID = 27, StudentName = "Test" });
```

Comment: Your `filteredStudentNames` is queried for  `s.age > 20` and so it won't exist

Comment: LINQ uses deferred execution. Created queries are only executed when you do `foreach` on them or use another execution techniques (like `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault`).

Comment: Also you are not adding new student with age>20. Sid you try that?

Comment: Probably a typo- you meant to write `studentList.Add(new Student { StudentID = 6, StudentName = "Test", age=27 });`

Comment: Ofir is right, that's just a typo question and can be closed. If OP had a real world issue he needs to show the real code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes sir .. it was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filteredStudentNames` is queried with condition `age > 20`. On adding new Student you have not initiated the age property which means by default it is 0.

So it is not reflecting in `filteredStudentNames`

Try initiating the `age` property and then query the `Count`

```
studentList.Add(new Student { StudentID = 6, StudentName = "Test", age = 21 });
```

Count:

```
Console.WriteLine("filteredStudentNames: " + filteredStudentNames.Count()); //Output: 3
Console.WriteLine("studentNames: " + studentNames.Count());   //Output: 6
```

Comment: `StudentID = 27` is probably a typo, the ID should be `6` in this example and the age `27`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Yes. it should be, I have just re-used the example as in the question.

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 Thanks.. it was a typo.. silly mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure this will be work for you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", age = 18 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  age = 21 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  age = 18 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , age = 20  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , age = 21 }
            };

    var filteredStudentNames = from s in studentList where s.age > 20
                       select s;

    var studentNames = from s in studentList
                       select s;

    IList<Student> stud = studentList;
    studentList.Add(new Student { StudentID = 27, StudentName = "Test", age = 25 });


    var filteredStudentNames = from s in studentList where s.age > 20
                       select s;

}
```

You have to execute link after the adding by new entry and you have to add age for the new entry.
Thanks.

Comment: `You have to execute link after the adding by new entry.` No you don't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq Also, your code does not compile.