# Linq: Select with and without ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, pointers, function-pointers

Can anyone explain this behavior?

this code work:

```
Dictionary<string, int> fullPathTabAssociation = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    //bla bla.. 
    //here fullPathTabAssociation is populated
    ////bla bla.. 

var newValues = fullPathTabAssociation
  .Where(x => x.Value > index)
  .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value - 1))
  .ToList();

fullPathTabAssociation.Clear();

/*now newValues is populated with correct values*/
```

this code doesn't work

```
Dictionary<string, int> fullPathTabAssociation = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    //bla bla.. 
    //here fullPathTabAssociation is populated
    ////bla bla.. 

var newValues = fullPathTabAssociation
  .Where(x => x.Value > index)
  .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value - 1))

fullPathTabAssociation.Clear();

 /*now newValues is empty*/
```

The select function seems return a new `IEnumerable`, with the debug before `fullPathTabAssociation.Clear()` in both cases the values is correct for `newValues` and are different from `fullPathTabAssociation`. Specially I do not understand what happens in the last case

Comment: *Linq* is **lazy** it does its work on *materialization* (`.ToList()`) only.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq

Comment: A (deferred executed) LINQ query is just a query. It describes what has to be done to retrieve what you want. It is not yet executed. If you append `ToList` you _materialize_ this query and fill the result into a list. Your query's source is the dictionary, if you clear it the query will return nothing. If you first fill the result into a list, this will not be cleared if you clear the dictionary because the list is not coupled to the dictionary.

Comment: thank you, deferred behavior was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq is *lazy*; it postpones its work as far as it can (up to `foreach` or some kind of *materialization*).

In the first excerpt you materialize the query with `.ToList()` here Linq has to execute and provide `List<T>` collection:

```
var newValues = fullPathTabAssociation
  .Where(x => x.Value > index)
  .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value - 1))
  .ToList(); // <- Materizataion an actual List<T> required; Linq executes 

// Since we have newValues collection (not query) it doesn't depend on аullPathTabAssociation
fullPathTabAssociation.Clear();
```

In the second excerpt Linq *doesn't have to do* anything:

```
// Just a query, no materialization
var newValues = fullPathTabAssociation
  .Where(x => x.Value > index)
  .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value - 1));

fullPathTabAssociation.Clear();

...

// Only here (on foreach or materialization) Linq has to execute the query; 
// and it takes fullPathTabAssociation (which is empty) 
foreach (var item in newValues) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that by using `ToList` you are executing the Linq query and creating new list. The contents of this newly created list are independent of `fullPathTabAssociation`.

In the second sample, you only store the query in `newValues`. The query is not executed yet and will only be executed after you cleared the source of the query. Thus, the result of the query is empty.