# Entity Framework does not see data in database until a DBSet is converted to a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I define the index API of a controller as the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Blog> GetDatas()
{
    return _context.Blogs;
}
```

This always returns empty even-thought the database contains many `blog`s. However, when I do the following for *test reasons* only, entity framework manages to see the data and can return all the `blog`s in the database:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Blog> GetDatas()
{
    var blogs = _context.blogs.ToList();
    return _context.Blogs;
}
```

Any thoughts?

(maybe related to my [other unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420910/the-target-process-exited-with-code-0-while-evaluating-the-function-system-linq?noredirect=1#comment103184816_58420910)).

### Update 1

To avoid confusion around deferred execution in LINQ; I've tried the following two methods and using neither of the methods the returned json object contains the information already in the database. In other words, the serialized objects do not reflect entities persisted in the database. I think these methods would trigger execution of LINQ query, correct?

```
// Method 1:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Blog>>> GetDatas()
{
    return await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Method 2:
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Blog> GetDatas()
{
    return _context.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

Comment: That's how it works. A Linq query will not execute until something is called that requests the data.

Comment: does not make sense.

Comment: again, I don't understand; `_context.Blogs` should return otherwise it does not make any sense (at least to me) to have it while you need to perform another operation before it can be populated.

Comment: It is also according to the documentation. Microsoft docs isn't that bad. The reasons for this are quite complex. For now it has to suffice that if you return just complex.Blogs, you return a Linq query and not the result of the query.

Comment: The statement "it doesn't work" is relatively useless on stackoverflow. Please state explicitly your expected outcome vs your observed outcome

Comment: @CaiusJard updated, see if it relatively useful on stackoverflow now.

Comment: No, believe me it really works. You might not believe it, but there is someone already using it with success. Now you start to confuse deferred execution and async/await. What is the resulting json of method 2 that seems not to reflect the content of the db table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scoped or context pool for database instead of singleton or transient; i.e., use:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<BlogsContext>(options => {options.UseSqlServer();});
```

and avoid registrations such as (note `ServiceLifetime.Singleton`):

```
services.AddDbContext<BlogsContext>(options => {options.UseSqlServer();}, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, this is by design. See [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq) for an extended discussion but essentially data is loaded when it is used, not when it is requested. The only way you can see that it's empty is in the debugger; your runtime code doesn't see it that way because as soon as you try and find out whether the first form is empty or not it will fill with data, at which point (the point of use) it doesn't matter that it was empty up to that point - nothing was using it to find out whether it was empty or full

Think of it a bit like Schrondinger's cat

It's quite helpful actually:

```
var w = worldPopulation.Where(e => e.Gender = Gender.Male)

if(name!=null)
  w=w.Where(e=>e.Name == name)
```

The first query, if it ran immediately, could see 3.5 billion results being downloaded from your db to your client (a low spec machine compared with the server), then the name filter would reduce it to a few million. Better to only download a few million into your slow, low spec machine over a very slow network, in the first place.. right?

One benefit of only running the query when you actually ask for the data is that at that point you finally actually KNOW you want the data.  Up to that point you might never have needed it, so downloading it would be a waste of resources

Comment: does it mean `_context.Blogs` is executed using LINQ? the return object from this api is always serialized as JSON, would not be access to data to trigger execution?

Comment: It will fill when it's enumerated by the thing that is serializing to JSON..

Comment: Is it anyhow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58420910/947889) question?

Comment: At the point where Json would like to enumerate the query results you are outside of the DbContext, so that cannot force the query to execute

Comment: It is how it works and it makes perfectly sense and its the way it works since decades.

Comment: @DanielSchmid perfect is relative.

Comment: @CaiusJard my database service is scoped, hence at the time of serialization the context may not be accessible.

Comment: @DanielSchmid I think you did not understand the question, the point is not whether deferring execution to later in LINQ is a good decision or not.