# C# LINQ Multiple evaluation of the same data

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

Given a class that holds (and initializes once) an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Values = Sequence(0, 10).Select(i => Convert(i));
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; private set; }

    private static string Convert(int i)
    {
        string iStr = i.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Convert: " + iStr);
        return iStr;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Sequence(int start, int end)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1);
    }
}
```

Why does every usage that requires the evaluated values of `myClass.Values` re-evaluates them?

e.g.:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    foreach (var v in myClass.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v);
    }
    foreach (var v in myClass.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + v);
    }
}
```

This will print 20 times "Convert: " and "Value: ".

I know that saving the Values as a list (with `ToList()` for example) will solve this, but it was my understanding that once Values are evaluated the values will be used from memory (as if I used `Lazy<T>` and then `Values.value`), why is this not the same case?

Comment: *Materialize* (`.ToArray()`, `.ToList()`) i.e. store the results in a collection and they will be computed once.

Comment: Take a look at this: [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of `IEnumerable<T>`. Your projection call `Select` is actually invoked for every item in the collection (but apparently you only called it once)when each item is called in the `foreach` loop.

So when you are looping with `foreach` loop the `IEnumerable` object is calling the enumerator and getting the next item if any available in the collection something similar to state machine.

It keeps track of the current item being enumerated when next item is request in the foreach loop it is called again so resulting the `Convert` method to be called again.

Comment: I was going to ask what is the benefit of using LINQ in that case but I saw the comment about [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)