# Why are these tasks executed twice?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to asynchronously add multiple entities to my database, as the "arrange" part of my integration test.

However, I'm getting double entries with my original code:

```
private async Task<Foo[]> GenerateFoos(params string[] names)
{
    var tasks = names.Select(async name =>
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { Name = name };
        await AddAsync(foo);
        return foo;
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return tasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();
}

[Test]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    var expected = await GenerateFoos("A", "B", "C");
}
```

It generates double the amount of objects (two of each) in my database, and I can't figure out why.

I've looked up other examples online but they all assume that the async method (`AddAsync` in my case) returns the objects I'm looking to return, but that is not the case here; as `AddAsync` only returns the ID, but I want to return the added object itself.

I've reworked the code twice and these two alternatives do not insert duplicate:

```
// Alternative 1
    
var result = new List<Corporation>();
        
foreach (var name in names)
{
    var foo= new Foo() { Name = name };
    await AddAsync(foo);
    result.Add(foo);
}

return result.ToArray();

// Alternative 2

var foos = names.Select(name => new Foo{ Name = name });

await Task.WhenAll(foos.Select(foo => AddAsync(foo)));

return foos.ToArray();
```

So I'm pretty sure the error stems from my code, not that of `AddAsync`. But I don't see why the first one is behaving differently. While I don't expect the content of `AddAsync` matters here, I'm adding it for completion's sake:

```
public static async Task AddAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

    context.Add(entity);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Can anyone spot why my tasks are being executed twice?

Comment: `tasks = names.Select(...).ToList()`?

Comment: @GSerg: It does solve the problem, so it'll be a double enumeration issue (I would expect to be warned about that but apparently not...). Can you explain where/why the double enumeration is taking place? Post an answer and you'll get the tick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var tasks` contains a query, [not the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7324033/11683) of a query.

This query is enumerated twice, on `Task.WhenAll()` and on `tasks.Select()`.
Because the call to `AddAsync` is inside a function created during the enumeration, it is executed twice.

Materializing the query solves the problem:

```cs
var tasks = names.Select(async name =>
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { Name = name };
        await AddAsync(foo);
        return foo;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Note that your Alternative 2 contains the same double enumeration problem, but this time the enumeration only causes new instances of `Foo` to be unnecessarily created. The calls to `AddAsync` are outside of the enumeration.