# Why foreach loop works but Linq variant doesn't?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I wanted to fill WinForms Combobox with enum values, yet when I tried to do it with Linq, no items were added to the Combobox. However, the foreach variant works just fine.

My Linq:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(AgeCategory))
    .Select(x => cbCategory.Items.Add(x));
```

My foreach:

```
foreach (var category in Enum.GetNames(typeof(AgeCategory)))
{
    cbCategory.Items.Add(category);
}
```

Also, if you know about a better way to do this, I'm open to different solutions.

Comment: The Linq version is faulty: the Select method does a projection to create a collection of items, but here you are just calling a method that returns an index ... so, why not? Otherwise you don't [execute the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation), therefore nothing is done, unless for example you call ToList. Personally, I found such code esoteric, not clean, and to avoid, in addition to be not efficient, and therefore *dangerous*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) is using [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation). That means it's executed if you use a `foreach` or other method like `ToList`/`ToArray`. Until then it just builds the *query*.

So why that compiles at all, what you are doing there? You have to look at [`ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add?view=net-5.0) to see that it's not `void`(returns nothing) but returns the index of the item that you have added. So you are selecting integers here, which is not what you want.

You could use this approach:

```
cbCategory.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(AgeCategory)));
```

As a rule of thumb: use LIN*Q* to query something not to modify(add) something.

Worth reading: [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)