# Channel multiple producers and consumers

Tags: c#, channel, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

I have the below code:

```
var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

var consumers = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 5)   
    .Select(consumerNumber =>
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            while (await channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
            {
                if (channel.Reader.TryRead(out var item))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {item} on consumer {consumerNumber}");
                }
            }
        }));

var producers = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 5)    
    .Select(producerNumber =>
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var t = $"Message {i}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Producing {t} on producer {producerNumber}");

                await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(t);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.Next(3)));
            }
        }));

await Task.WhenAll(producers)
    .ContinueWith(_ => channel.Writer.Complete());

await Task.WhenAll(consumers);
```

Which works as it should however im wanting it to consume at the same time as producing. However

```
await Task.WhenAll(producers)
    .ContinueWith(_ => channel.Writer.Complete());
```

Blocks the consumer from running until its complete and I can't think of a way of getting them both to run?

Comment: You can improve your code a *lot* if you use some Channel coding patterns. The problem isn't `await Task.WhenAll` and there's nothing wrong with `ContinueWith` if used properly. There *are* problems with throwing exceptions to simulate control flow though

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how channels can be used to not only simplify the code but make coordination, composition and error handling a *lot* easier

Comment: Worse, if you use exception blocks to complete the channel, the *consumer* will never know the producer threw. In this case it may not matter a lot but in production code this could cause eg a database consumer to commit changes even after errors

Comment: Now that .NET 6 is almost out, you can simplify the idiomatic way of using multiple consumers with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, eg `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(token),new (){MaxDegreeOfParallelism=3},item=>Console.WriteLine(item))`. You'll have to completely rewrite non-idiomatic code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `consumers` and `producers` variables are of type `IEnumerable<Task>`. This a [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq) enumerable, that needs to be materialized in order for the tasks to be created. You can materialize the enumerable by chaining the `ToArray` operator on the LINQ queries. By doing so, the type of the two variables will become `Task[]`, which means that your tasks are instantiated and up and running.

As a side note, the `ContinueWith` method requires passing explicitly the `TaskScheduler.Default` as an argument, otherwise you are at the mercy of whatever the `TaskScheduler.Current` may be (it might be the UI `TaskScheduler` for example). This is the correct usage of `ContinueWith`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(producers)
    .ContinueWith(_ => channel.Writer.Complete(), TaskScheduler.Default);
```

1. Code analyzer CA2008: [Do not create tasks without passing a `TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008)
2. *"[...] This is why in production library code I write, I always explicitly specify the scheduler I want to use."* ([Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5/))

Another problem is that any exceptions thrown by the `producers` will be swallowed, because the tasks are not awaited. Only the continuation is awaited, which is unlikely to fail. To solve this problem, you could just ditch the [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) `ContinueWith`, and instead use async-await composition (an async [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that awaits the `producers` and then completes the channel). In this case not even that is necessary. You could simply do this:

```
try { await Task.WhenAll(producers); }
finally { channel.Writer.Complete(); }
```

The channel will `Complete` after any outcome of the `Task.WhenAll(producers)` task, and so the `consumers` will not get stuck.

A third problem is that a failure of some of the `producers` will cause the immediate termination of the current method, before awaiting the `consumers`. These tasks will then become fire-and-forget tasks. I am leaving it to you to find how you can ensure that **all** tasks can be awaited, in all cases, before exiting the method either successfully or with an error.

Comment: @Houlahan not quite. There's nothing wrong with `ContinueWith` in this context. You don't care what thread is used to call `writer.Complete()` *at all*. On the other hand, using exceptions as incomplete control flow like this is a problem : it's expensive, harder to debug but worse, worker exceptions are never sent to downstream channels that never realize the producer aborted.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues with the code, including forgetting to enumate the `producers` and `consumers` enumerables. `IEnumerable` is evaluated lazily, so until you actually enumerate it with eg `foreach` or `ToList`, nothing is generated.

There's nothing wrong with `ContinueWith` when used properly either. It's definitely better and cheaper than using exceptions as control flow.

The code can be improved a *lot* by using some common Channel coding patterns.

1. The producer owns and encapsulates the channel
2. The producer exposes only Reader(s)

Plus, `ContinueWith` is an *excellent* choice to signal a ChannelWriter's completion, as we *don't care at all* which thread will do that. If anything, we'd prefer to use one of the "worker" threads to avoid a thread switch.

Let's say the producer function is:

```
async Task Produce(ChannelWriter<string> writer, int producerNumber)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var t = $"Message {i}";
            Console.WriteLine($"Producing {t} on producer {producerNumber}");

            await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(t);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.Next(3)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer**

The producer can be :

```
ChannelReader<string> ProduceData(int dop)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,dop)
                 .Select(producerNumber => Produce(producerNumber))
                 .ToList();
    _ =Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
                       .
    
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

**Completion and error propagation**

Notice the line :

```
_ =Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
```

This says that as soon as the producers complete, the writer itself should complete with any exception that may be raised. It doesn't really matter what thread the continuation runs on as it doesn't do anything other than call `TryComplete`.

More importantly, `t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception)` propagates the worker exception(s) to downstream consumers. Otherwise the consumers would never know something went wrong. If you had a database consumer you'd want it to avoid finalizing any changes if the source aborted.

**Consumer**

The consumer method can be:

```
async Task Consume(ChannelReader<string> reader,int dop,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var tasks= Enumerable
        .Range(1, dop)   
        .Select(consumerNumber =>
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await foreach(var item in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {item} on consumer {consumerNumber}");
                }
            }));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

In this case `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` enumerates the worker tasks thus starting them.

Nothing else is needed to produce all generated messages. When all producers finish, the `Channel.Reader` is completed. When that happens, `ReadAllAsync` will keep offering all remaining messages to the consumers and exit.

**Composition**

Combining both methods is as easy as:

```
var reader=Produce(10);
await Consume(reader);
```

**General Pattern**

This is a general pattern for pipeline stages using Channels - read the input from a ChannelReader, write it to an internal Channel and return only the owned channel's Reader. This way the stage owns the channel which makes completion and error handling a *lot* easier:

```
static ChannelReader<TOut> Crunch<Tin,TOut>(this ChannelReader<Tin>,int dop=1,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<TOut>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,dop)
              .Select(async i=>Task.Run(async ()=>
              {
                  await(var item in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          ...
                          await writer.WriteAsync(msg);
                      }
                      catch(Exception exc)
                      {
                          //Handle the exception and keep processing messages
                      }
                  }
              },token));
    _ =Task.WhenAll(tasks)
           .ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

This allows chaining multiple "stages" together to form a pipeline:

```
var finalReader=Producer(...)
                .Crunch1()
                .Crunch2(10)
                .Crunch3();
await foreach(var result in finalReader.ReadAllAsync())
{
...
}
```

Producer and consumer methods can be written in the same way, allowing, eg the creation of a data import pipeline:

```
var importTask = ReadFiles<string>(somePath)
                  .ParseCsv<string,Record[]>(10)
                  .ImportToDb<Record>(connectionString);

await importTask;
```

With `ReadFiles`

```
static ChannelReader<string> ReadFiles(string folder)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    var task=Task.Run(async ()=>{
        foreach(var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder,"*.csv"))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(path);
        }
    });
    task.ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

**Update for .NET 6 Parallel.ForEachAsync**

Now that .NET 6 is supported in production, one could use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to simplify a concurrent consumer to :

```
static ChannelReader<TOut> Crunch<Tin,TOut>(this ChannelReader<Tin>,
                           int dop=1,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<TOut>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    var dop=new ParallelOptions { 
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop,
                CancellationToken = token
    };
    var task=Parallel.ForEachAsync(
                 reader.ReadAllAsync(token),
                 dop,
                 async item =>{
                      try
                      {
                          ...
                          await writer.WriteAsync(msg);
                      }
                      catch(Exception exc)
                      {
                          //Handle the exception and keep processing messages
                      }
                  });
    task.ContinueWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
    return channel.Reader;
}
```