# .Result operation doesn't block

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, blocking

I expect the following code to be blocked for almost 5 secs, but it is not. It immediately prints. Isn't `Result` operation blocking?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Return a value type with a lambda expression
        Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(5000).Id + 100);
        int i = task1.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the intention behind the `Task.Delay(5000).Id + 100` expression? Adding a number to an ID seems nonsensical. IDs, much like phone numbers, are not intended for doing math.

Comment: @Theodor I assume it's just to give the task an int result that involves the contents of the operation in some way, not for any practical use

Comment: `Task.Delay` returns a `Task` that you have to wait on in order to "block" for the specified amount of time.

Comment: Would it make sense to you if I said "change your code to say `Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => { var t = Task.Delay(5000); t.Wait();return t.Id + 100;});` ?

Answer (score 5):

This code is not waiting for `Delay` to finish. It starts the delay and then return immediately `Id+100`. So, when the code reaches the `Result` operation, the `task1` is almost always is in `Completed` state, so you get `Result` immediately.

You can try following to get desired behaviour

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000).Id + 100);
int i = task1.Result;
```

Or better, use `await` instead of `Result` everywhere

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000).Id + 100);
int i = await task1;
```

or even

```
int i = await Task.Delay(5000).Id + 100
```

(but I'm unsure here as you may have more logic inside the task in actual code)

Comment: Are you sure about using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` [with asynchronous lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task)?

Comment: Hm. yes, you are correct - `StartNew` will not work with async, only `Task.Run` will. I corrected the answer. Thank you!

Comment: what is the difference btw `task1.Result` and `await task1;` ? Don't they allow the caller thread to continue? such as `Console.WriteLine("it prints before task1.Result"); task1.Result`

Comment: `Result` will block the current thread until the task will finish and result will be awailable. `Await` will wait asynchrnously and let the current thread to do other things then resume execution from `await` point after the result will be awailable.  See here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result

Answer (score 1):

To me [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0) seems more natural for what you're trying to do:

```
Task<int> t = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(delayTask => delayTask.Id + 100);
Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
```

This will execute the delay task and then execute the lambda in `ContinueWith` after the delay is complete.

Comment: Be careful with the `ContinueWith` method. If you have to use it, you [should specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254023/channel-multiple-producers-and-consumers/69254906#69254906) the `scheduler` argument to avoid unpleasant surprises.