# What is the difference when converting the Linq result to ToList() and when not converting it toList

Tags: linq, tolist

In the below example when I donot use `.ToList()` in the Line -  `var b = a.SelectMany(x => a.Select(y => { ans.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)); return false; })).ToList();`

The Count of `ans` is `0`

Can someone explain what exactly happening here with and without `.ToList();`

```
 public void selectAll()
    {
        var ans = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        var a = new List<int>()
        {
            1,2,3
        };
        var b = a.SelectMany(x => a.Select(y => { ans.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y)); return false; })).ToList();
        foreach (var item in ans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Item1},{item.Item2}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. You are abusing LINQ by calling methods with side effects (`ans.Add`). That is not the intent of LINQ - it is for filtering and querying, not modifications or side effects (except in special rare cases). 2. LINQ uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution) for most operators - that means the query is not processed until instantiated in some way, either by a `foreach` or by a method like `ToList` or `Count` or `First`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use side effects use something like this:

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
var ans =  a.Select(x => a.Select(y => new Tuple<int, int>(x, y))).SelectMany(z => z);
foreach (var item in ans)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Item1},{item.Item2}");
}
```