# How to run parallel code for multiple search methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm working on a code I would like to improve. It is a search method. Based on an input I would like to search this value in multiple tables of my database.

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResponseModel>> Search(string input)
        {
            var listOfSearchResponse = new List<SearchResponseModel>();
            listOfSearchResponse.AddRange(await SearchOrder(input)),
            listOfSearchResponse.AddRange(await SearchJob(input));
            listOfSearchResponse.AddRange(await SearchClient(input));
            listOfSearchResponse.AddRange(await SearchItem(input));
            listOfSearchResponse.AddRange(await SearchProduction(input));
            return listOfSearchResponse;
        }
```

I use the work await because every search is defined like this one:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResponseModel>> SearchOrder(string input) {...}
```

My five search methods are not yet really async. They all execute in sequence after the previous one. What should I do from here to make them parallel?

Comment: The bottleneck is the I/O the query involve. You can very well parallelize computations; I/O does not scale well.

Comment: [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0) should be your friend. you can start them all in parallel and await and harvest the results in the last line with this call. then you can use addrange

Comment: Could you include the code inside the `SearchOrder` method? A return value of `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` is quite strange. Are you returning a [deferred enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq) or a materialized collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that something like this should work, in theory:

```cs
var tasks = new[]
            {
                SearchOrder(input),
                SearchJob(input),
                SearchClient(input),
                SearchItem(input),
                SearchProduction(input)
            };

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

//var listOfSearchResponse = tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();
var listOfSearchResponse = tasks. SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
```

In practice, it's hard to know how much benefit you'll see.

Comment: Its work mentioning that [Task.WhenAll<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0)))))) will return an `TResult[]`.

Comment: when WhenAll is awaited it returns the resulting items. so there is no need to extra select them in the last line

Comment: I just changed the Select by SelectMany

Comment: It doesn't work. The system spend time on the first line. When I create the array, it uses 3 second. The await line happen in millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth considering using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
public IObservable<SearchResponseModel> SearchObservable(string input) =>
    Observable.Defer<SearchResponseModel>(() =>
        new []
        {
            Observable.FromAsync(() => SearchOrder(input)),
            Observable.FromAsync(() => SearchJob(input)),
            Observable.FromAsync(() => SearchClient(input)),
            Observable.FromAsync(() => SearchItem(input)),
            Observable.FromAsync(() => SearchProduction(input)),
        }
        .Merge()
        .SelectMany(x => x));
```

The advantage here is that as each search completes you get the partial results through from the observable - there's no need to wait until all the tasks have finished.

Observables signal each value as they are produced and they signal a finial completion so you know when all of the results are through.